# How to access android.R.id.home with Dot 42

Tags: c#, android, dot42

I am trying to translate the following into C# with Dot 42

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{ 
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
{ 
       case android.R.id.home: 
            return(true);
       case R.id.about: 
            return(true);
       case R.id.help: 
            return(true);
}
return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

My main problem right now is the android.id.home  The Intellisense does not show a Home member of Android.R.Id  What am I missing here?  BTW if you would like to translate the full block into C#, thanks, but I'm pretty sure the rest of it will not pose much a problem.

Comment: why using android.R.id.home: you need R.id.home:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(Android.View.IMenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.GetItemId())
    {
        case Android.R.Id.Home: // API level 11 and higher (Android 3.0) 
            return (true);
        case R.Id.About:
            return (true);
        case R.Id.Help:
            return (true);
    }
    return (base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Note that `R.Id.Home` identifies a resource in the platform, hence the `Android` scope.

[image]

Assumably, `About` and `Help` are application resource identifiers.

Comment: Yea, Home does not come up for me. my options say Hint then Icon.  Am I missing an using?

Comment: You don't need the using if you specify Android explicitly. I have no idea why the Home field doesn't show up. Does it compile?

Comment: Then it's probably an Intellisense artifact.

Comment: so should I try to just put Home in there and see if it compiles?

Comment: Tried it and I get                                                'Android.R.Id' does not contain a definition for 'Home'

Comment: Yes. I am surprised it doesn't show up. I understood it compiled.

Comment: Home was introduced in 3.0. What are you targeting?

Comment: That did it, I was targeting 2.3.3